# Revolution Slider images not displaying after I enable “Toolset Views” plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

The slider remains, but the images no longer show after I enable the "Toolset Views" plugin. I check the code, and this message appears where the image should be:

```
<!--Runtime Modification - Img tag is Still Available for SEO Goals in Source - <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="https://www.longbeachchiro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/LBSR_Slider3FINAL.jpg" alt="" title="LBSR_Slider3FINAL" width="1024" height="273" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg lazyload defaultimg" data-no-retina="">-->
```

Can anybody point me in a direction to diagnose this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case revolution slider images don't show when I enable the "Lazy Load Media" option of the SG Optimizer (SiteGround's cache and optimization plugin).

Tests should be done using an incognito window.